# Why are the given compounds in a homologous series?

Tags: terminology, hydrocarbons

Why are the given compounds in one homologous series?

$$\ce{CH3-OH}$$
  $$\ce{CH3-CH2-OH}$$
  $$\ce{CH3-CH2-CH2-OH}$$
  $$\ce{CH3-CH2-CH2-CH2-OH}$$

I know that homologous series can be represented by a common general formula and have the same chain length. But I could not answer this question. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You got it all wrong: compounds in a homologous series have **different** chain length.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin, I am sorry for that.

Answer (score 5):

Because they can all be described by the general formula $\ce{CH3-(CH2)_n-OH}$. The only varying parameter in this case is the number of middle $-\ce{CH2}- $ groups.

So while the the number of middle $-\ce{CH2}- $ groups may vary $\left(n = 0,1,2,\ldots\right)$ they all fit in this general formula.

The formula $\ce{CH3-(CH2)_n-OH}$ tells you that:

- The chain starts with a $\ce{CH3}-$ group
- The chain ends with an $-\ce{OH}$ group
- Contains a variable number, $n$, of $-\ce{CH2}-$ groups in between.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? @ttdijkstra

Comment: For the series in the question, another possibility is n=0

Comment: Thanks for the note on formatting @IͶΔ I just noticed myself.

Comment: Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation " latex="" ‎at="" chem.se""="), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/7448) and [this ‎one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/111/7448) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown. Welcome to chem.SE!

Comment: I cleaned up the formatting and the wording a bit, but @ttdijkstra nailed the correct idea.